# Facebook Server-Sent Events for Live Comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

I'm experimenting with [Facebook Server-Sent Events for Live Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/server-sent-events/endpoints/live-comments) (SSE) and I try to retrieve in real time every comments made on a live video stream displayed on a Facebook page.

The documentation states that "comments are prioritized based on quality so if the comment rate exceeds the requested rate then you will receive the higher quality comments.", but even if i'm below the rate (set at `ten_per_second`) some comments are filtered. The purpose of my experiment is to retrieve a pattern (an emoji) from the comments, it's not admissible for me to miss some of them.

The other approche I took is to use the [Live Video Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-video/comments/) endpoint but I can't get the user name who posts the comment I only get data like

```
{
  "created_time": "2018-11-14T12:39:01+0000",
  "message": "test message",
  "id": "2292500244366991_2292502427700106"
}
```

with a call to `<video-id>/comments?live_filter=no_filter&order=reverse_chronological&filter=stream`

Even with Page access_token I don't get these names and ids...

Does anyone succeed in retrieving every comments with poster name from a live video?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I had trouble with my page so I recreated one and now I manage to get the [Live Video Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-video/comments/) endpoint to work as expected. But still no luck [Facebook Server-Sent Events for Live Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/server-sent-events/endpoints/live-comments)!!!

I guess I have to stick with polling, deal with Facebook Graph API rate limits and forget streaming...

Comment: What do you need the emojis for?

Comment: It's for a game I'm building... But forget about the emoji, it's not really the problem.

Comment: Use `one_hundred_per_second`

Comment: I already tried `one_hundred_per_second` but with no luck... I already have trouble getting all messages at 1 per second post rate so `ten_per_second` should be enough...

Comment: Any chance you could state what recreating the page helped with?  I can't get this working either. Exact same issue.